# How can I disable my App from account with using sdk?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I created App which add infomation about read articles in my site to timetable.

How can I disable my app from users account with using facebook sdk?

E.g. User click a button on my site and App disabled from users account.

Comment: http://WhatHaveYouTried.com Why would you need to do this anyway? If the user doesn't want your app to post to their timeline anymore or wants to disable your app they can do that from FB's settings.

Comment: For usability. If user have possibility to add app on site, he must have possibility to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
FB.api("me/permissions", "delete", function(response) {
    console.log("Application should now be invalidated, response: ", response);
});
```